# Paginação PDO - Problemas com prepare(); select();

Tags: php, pdo, select, paginação

Olá, estou tendo os problemas para imprimir dados de uma tabela.

**Atualização**: Inseri as seguinte linhas no arquivo *conexao.php*:

```
public function select(){   
  $sth = $this->prepare("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");    
  $this->execute();     
  $result = $sth->fetchAll();   
  return $result; 
}
```

### conexao.php

```
// conexao banco de dados
<?php 
    class Conexao {
        private $data = array();
        //variavel da classe Base
        protected $pdo = null;

        public function __set($name, $value){
            $this->data[$name] = $value;
        }

        public function __get($name){
            if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
                return $this->data[$name];
            }

            $trace = debug_backtrace();
            trigger_error(
                'Undefined property via __get(): ' . $name .
                ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
                ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
                E_USER_NOTICE);
            return null;
        }

        //método que retorna a variável $pdo
        public function getPdo() {
            return $this->pdo;
        }

        //método construtor da classe
        function __construct($pdo = null) {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
            if ($this->pdo == null)
                $this->conectar();
        }

        //método que conecta com o banco de dados
        public function conectar() {            
            $local = "localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $pass = "";
            $basename = "diner";

            try {
                $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$local;dbname=$basename",
                                "$user",
                                "$pass",
                                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                die();
            }
        }

        //método que desconecta
        public function desconectar() {
            $this->pdo = null;
        }  

        public function select(){
            $pdo = $this->getPdo();  
            $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");    
            $sth->execute();    
            $result = $sth->fetchAll();  
            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

### lista-prato.php

```
//onde será imprimido os dados
<?php 
    //inclui as bibliotecas
    require_once('conexao.php');
    //faz a canexão 
    $pdo = new Conexao();

    // determina o numero de registros que serão visualisados
    $maximo = 20;
    // armazenamos o valor da pagina atual
    $pagina = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? ($_GET['pagina']) : '1';
    // subtraimos 1, por que os registros sempre começam do 0
    $inicio = $pagina - 1;
    //multiplicamos a quantidade de registros pelo valor da pagina atual
    $inicio = $maximo * $inicio;

    $strCount = $pdo->select("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'prato_id' FROM prato");
    $total = 0;
    if(count($strCount)){
        foreach ($strCoun as $row)  {
            // armazeno total de registros da tabela para fazer paginação
            $total = $row["id_prato"];
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Pagina&ccedil;&atilde;o com PHP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="tabela1">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="coluna1"/>
                <col class="coluna2"/>
                <col class="coluna3"/>
            </colgroup>
            <caption>Pagina&ccedil;&atilde;o com PHP</caption>          
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Municipio</th>
                    <th>UF</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                //se a tabela nao estiver vazia, percorremos linha por linha pegando os valores
                if(count($result)){
                    foreach ($result as $res) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "  <td>".$res['titulo']."</td>";
                        echo "  <td>".$res['descricao']."</td>";
                        echo "  <td>".$res['preco']."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";

                    }
                }
            ?>
            </tbody>          
        </table>
        <div id="paginação">
            <?
                //determina quantos links serão adicionados e removidos
            $max_links = 6;
            // dados para os botões
            $previous = $pagina - 1;
            $next = $pagina + 1;
            // usa função "ceil" para arredondar o numero
            $pgs = ceil($total / $maximo);
            //se a tabela nao for vazia, adicionar botões
            if($pgs > 1){
                echo "<br/>";
                //botao anterior
                if($previous > 0){
                    echo "<div id='botaoprox'><a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pagina=$previous><input type='submit' name='bt-enviar' id='bt-enviar' value='Anterior' class='button' /></a></div>";
                }else{
                    echo "<div id='botaoanteriorDis'><a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pagina=$previous><input type='submit'  name='bt-enviar' id='bt-enviar' value='Anterior' class='button' disabled='disabled'/></a></div>";
                }
            }
            echo "div id='numpag'>";
                for($i=$pagina-$max_links; $i <= $pgs-1; $i++) {
                    if ($i <= 0){
                        //enquanto for negativo, não faz nada
                    }else{
                        //senão adiciona o link para a outra página
                        if($i == $pgs){
                        //se for o final da pagina, coloca ...
                            echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pagina=".($i).">$i</a> ..."; 
                        }
                    }
                }

            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Página interna onde será exibido o resultado **interno.php**:

```
<?php 
require_once 'usuario.php';
require_once 'sessao.php';
require_once 'autenticador.php';

$aut = Autenticador::instanciar();

$usuario = null;
if ($aut->esta_logado()) {
    $usuario = $aut->pegar_usuario();
}
else {
    $aut->expulsar();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Pagina interna</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Página interna do sistema</h1>
        <p>Você está logado como 
            <strong><?php print $usuario->getNome(); ?></strong>.
        </p>
        <p><a href="controle.php?acao=sair">Sair</a></p>

<?php include 'form-insert.php' ?>


<?php include 'lista-prato.php' ?>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Erro** (já solucionado nas respostas):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\login\lista-prato.php on line 1021

**Atualização 2:** Ele está retornando o seguinte erro (já solucionado nos comentários):

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method Conexao::prepare() in C:\wamp\www\login\conexao.php on line 58

**Atualização 3**:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp\www\PROJETOS\210DINER\site-definitivo\newdiner\login\lista-prato.php on line 54
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0529  245376  {main}( )   ..\interno.php:0
2   0.0597  315008  include( 'C:\wamp\www\login\lista-prato.php' )  ..\interno.php:34
```

Alguém ai sabe onde estou errando e como devo proceder? Tenho que criar o método `prepare()`? em uma `function`? como fiz com `select`? ou não precisa de `prepare`, posso executar o `select` de uma vez?

Comment: [`Prepare`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php) é um método do PDO. Na linha *58* deixe assim: `$sth = $this->$pdo->prepare("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");  $this->$pdo->execute();` e não somente `$this`. Outra coisa, no arquivo *lista-prato.php* você chama esse método assim: `$pdo->select("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'prato_id0' FROM prato");`, tem certeza que é isso mesmo?

Comment: realmente, tinha um 0 que não deveria. alterei o código para o que sugeriu. 
`public function select(){   
      $sth = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");  
      $this->pdo->execute();  
      $result = $sth->fetchAll();  
      return $result; }
` se for isso, deu erro.
**( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\wamp\www\login\conexao.php on line 59**

Comment: Ops, deixe essa função assim: http://pastebin.com/TVnECSg3 repare também que no arquivo *lista-prato.php* você chama o método `select` com argumentos, sendo que no *conexao.php* ela não recebe.

Comment: errors:

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\wamp\www\login\conexao.php on line 58**
______________________
**Notice: Undefined property via __get(): in C:\wamp\www\login\conexao.php on line 58 in C:\wamp\www\login\conexao.php on line 21**
_______________________
**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\login\conexao.php on line 58**

Comment: Está falando do COUNT ? então, fiquei bem confuso..

Comment: Isso, repare que você chama ela com argumentos, mas você não usa parâmetros na função. Sobre o erro, você tem um método que já retorna a variável `pdo`, a função `getPdo` use ela. http://pastebin.com/kCQmHn8z

Comment: Beleza, atualizei a pergunta. Retornou o erro:
`( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: resultado in C:\wamp\www\PROJETOS\210DINER\site-definitivo\newdiner\login\lista-prato.php on line 54`

Comment: Essa variável não está definida, não era para ser `strCount`?

Comment: Beleza, pararam os erros. mas não está imprimindo os dados do banco!

Comment: deixei assim ó: http://pastebin.com/Pd0rczsK 
ele imprime:  **Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\PROJETOS\210DINER\site-definitivo\newdiner\login\lista-prato.php on line 27** e embaixo um do erro imprime na tela **'Array'**

Comment: Faça assim: `echo "<pre>" . print_r($resultados, 1) . "<pre>";`

Comment: imprimiu: **Array
(
)**

Comment: Independentemente de como você chamar o método `select`, a *query* que vai executar sempre será `SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato` que está definida no corpo da função.

Comment: Então.. ele imprime um Array vazio, alterei no corpo da função todos os select do código chamam os dados. 
`("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");  `
http://pastebin.com/K4eeQsGg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além dos erros de *sintaxe* no `if`, há também um erro na tua função `select`:

```
public function select(){   
  $sth = $this->prepare("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");    
  $this->execute();     
  $result = $sth->fetchAll();   
  return $result;
}
```

Você está chamando o método [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php) a partir do `$this`, o que causa o erro `Call to undefined method`, é necessário chamar este método a partir do objeto PDO, no teu código ele é retornado na função `getPdo()`. Portanto, a função `select` deve ficar assim:

```
public function select($statement){
  $pdo = $this->getPdo();  
  $sth = $pdo->prepare($statement);    
  $sth->execute();    
  $result = $sth->fetchAll();  
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: `$statement` aí seria: `("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");`  quando for chamar eu declaro `$statement = ("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");`   ?

Comment: @manzetti.denis Não.. deixe o *conexao.php* assim: **http://pastebin.com/kXK2zTwW** e o *lista-prato.php*: **http://pastebin.com/EFdjnBny**. Não testei.

Comment: Acho que consegui. http://pastebin.com/QudNWmXA - porem ele imprime os valores da seguinte forma: http://pastebin.com/4jqNyxzx . Como eu faço para tratar esses dados e imprimir os campos separando por linhas? devo abrir uma nova pergunta?

Comment: @manzetti.denis Que bom que conseguiu. Acho que seria melhor abrir uma nova pergunta sim, porque essa já está bem extensa com tantos "updates". =) se possível marque uma das respostas também.

Answer (score 2):

É um erro de sintaxe, falou fechar uma chave em `if(count($strCount)){`, mude seu código para:

```
if(count($strCount)){
    foreach ($strCoun as $row)  {
        // armazeno total de registros da tabela para fazer paginação
        $total = $row["id_prato"];
    }
}// <---- chave que faltava.
```

Comment: Fiz o que você falou e deu:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Conexao::select() in C:\wamp\www\login\lista-prato.php on line 17;`

Comment: Na classe conexão não existe esse método select, deve ser em outra, ou vc deve adicionar esse método. @manzetti.denis

Comment: como eu faria isso?
`public function select();{
$pdo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");
$pdo->execute();
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
}`

estou iniciando php, não peguei bem as funções.

Comment: Mais ou menos esse o código, no final adicione um `return $result;`, em qual classe ele estava? @manzetti.denis

Comment: eu acabei de criar..  vou adiciona-lo dentro de `class Conexão()`

Comment: O código é esse: `public function select(){ 
 $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");
 $pdo->execute();
 $result = $sth->fetchAll();
 return $result;
}` @manzetti.denis

Comment: certo @rray, editei a pergunta com o novo erro.. ele retornou agora para o prepare(); tenho que criar como o select? como eu faria? na verade.. é necessario o prepare?

Answer (score 2):

Você não fechou corretamente este `if`

```
if(count($strCount)){
    foreach ($strCoun as $row  {
        // armazeno total de registros da tabela para fazer paginação
        $total = $row["id_prato"]
    });
```

deve ser desta forma:

```
if(count($strCount)){
    foreach ($strCoun as $row) {
        // armazeno total de registros da tabela para fazer paginação
        $total = $row["id_prato"]
    };
}
```